# Odds ratio and 95% CI for interaction in logistic model in R

Tags: r, sas, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic model with an interaction between a dichotomous and a continuous variable:

```
aidslogit<-glm(cd4~ AGE+ANTIRET+AGE*ANTIRET, data = aidsdata, family = "binomial")
summary(aidslogit, digits=3)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.870  -1.190   0.771   1.056   1.586  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -0.599565   0.313241  -1.914   0.0556 .  
AGE            -0.008340   0.008849  -0.942   0.3459    
ANTIRET         1.308591   0.198031   6.608  3.9e-11 ***
AGE:ANTIRET    -0.013547   0.005507  -2.460   0.0139 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 9832.8  on 7264  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 9434.9  on 7261  degrees of freedom
  (654 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 9442.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

What I would like to do is calculate the OR and 95% CI for antiretroviral use at different ages, i.e, at age 20, 30, and 40.  I guess I could output the covariances and do it by hand, but it seems like there must be a way to do it automatically.

**For comparison:**

In SAS it would look like this:

```
proc logistic data=aidsdata descending;
model cd4=antiret age antiret*age;
oddsratio antiret /at (age=20 30 40);
run;
```

Comment: check out the `emmeans` package.

Answer (score 1):

For a regression without interactions, the odds ratio for each coefficient is `exp(coef(aidslogit))`. These are the odds ratios for a one-unit change in a given variable.

But with an interaction, you need to include both the main effect and the interaction. In this case, `AGE` is the second coefficient and `AGE:ANTIRET` is the fourth coefficient, so:

```
# Odds ratio for a one-unit change in AGE when ANTIRET=0
OR = exp(coef(aidslogit)[2])

# Odds ratio for a one-unit change in AGE when ANTIRET=1
OR = exp(coef(aidslogit)[2] + coef(aidslogit)[4])
```

To calculate the odds ratio for other `AGE` differences, multiply the coefficients by that amount. For example, to get the odds ratio for a 10-unit change in `AGE`:

```
# Odds ratio for a 10-unit change in AGE when ANTIRET=0
OR = exp(10 * coef(aidslogit)[2])

# Odds ratio for a 10-unit change in AGE when ANTIRET=1
OR = exp(10 * (coef(aidslogit)[2] + coef(aidslogit)[4]))
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have added that the bigger issue is to get the confidence interval.

Comment: In that case, let us know if `emmeans` (as suggested above by @BenBollker) does what you need.

Comment: If I mess around with emmeans enough I can get the beta coefficients and associated SE, but I haven't been able to get it to directly output odds ratios for that kind of analysis.  (I'm sure there's a way; I am not a proficient R user.)  If someone can post code I would appreciate it.